# Hard edges on bucket fill tool in Gimp

Tags: gimp, pixel, fill

I am trying to fill a selected region using the bucket tool in Gimp. I want everything to have hard edges, no gradual shading unless I do it myself. However, when I fill the region I end up getting gradual shading on the periphery. Here is an example image:
[image]

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 17):

After a few minutes more of poking around in Gimp I finally noticed that the selection tool had an anti-aliasing option, that was turned on. If this is not selected you get hard edged fills.

Comment: Indeed. Selection softening/feathering is what is responsible for this effect. If you have a soft selection from another source, you can straighten it using the `selections->threshold` action.

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks for the hint! So if you do a "Path to selection" you cannot choose aliasing, but the "sharpen" tool does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Gimp, the checkbox *Antialiasing* is checked and disabled (at least for the rectangular selection tool). You can achieve an sharp selection without antialiasing by making your selection and using *Select → Sharpen* from the menu.

**Update** Only using *Select > Border...* on a rectangular selection creates a seemingly rectangular selection with anti-aliasing. A normal rectangular selection is not anti-aliased and thus sharp.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. I can only see that *antialiasing* is locked to active for rectangle select, which is not surprising since there is no need for antialiasing for any rectangle aligning with the pixel grid. Still, *sharpen* may be an alternative to solving the asker’s problem.

Comment: Thank you for the greeting and enhancing the style of my answer, truly appreciated. I'm not sure I'm understanding the term anti-aliasing correctly. My current understanding is, that anti-aliasing means adding shades of the color of the line around the actual line so it seems smoother.

Comment: *My current understanding is, that anti-aliasing means adding shades of the color of the line around the actual line so it seems smoother.* – Yes, or in this case, modifying the intensity of the selection. Aliasing are artefacts caused by forcing a shape onto a pixel grid that cannot be perfectly represented on it. However, rectangles can be perfectly represented on a pixel grid and hence Gimp does not have to anti-alias when using a rectangle select. This is probably why you see it disabled. You should see it enabled for other kinds of selection (ellipse, free form, …).

Comment: I was led astray by the _Select > Border..._ feature which created an anti-aliased selection. The normal rectangular selection works fine without antialiasing. I updated my answer to include that.